# Change the amount of maximum Ram one app is allowed to use in Android device

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

**SCENARIO:**

App requires to store large amount of data in static scope. Because, after using SQLite previously, there are around 20 database calls with SELECT query including LIMITS AND BETWEEN in order to complete the whole scenario and the total time to query becomes unacceptable as this calculation might get repeated several times so making 20 DB calls for every iterations which makes the app behavior unacceptable.

So the strategy decided by the team is to make data available in static scope and select data directly from these variables as indexes and all the other information is available to produce further results.

**PROBLEM:**

I am using device with 8Gb ram and increase the heap size to 4G inside android studio.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
```

provides me the information about the Ram that my app can use which is around 604 Mb. So when the app starts copying the variables and as their size grows, apps get killed with OutOfMemory error when it reaches around 600 Mb range as debugged through Profiler.

Now what I want to know is:

1). What are the options I have to increase the Ram usage inside Android system. Is there any ways I can use to increase this ram limit for my app.

2). MORE IMPORTANTLY, Is it even possible to alternate this default memory size given to each app by Android system .. Will it be allowed if one tries to ROOT the device and achieve it somehow. I am already using largeHeap flag inside manifest.

Any help/guidance/directions will be helpful.

Comment: In your manifest you can request extra heap, but it does not explicitly guarantee a certain size: android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention but that is already added in manifest. By adding it, the app size grows upto 604mb. Otherwise OutOfMemory is thrown around 200 - 250 mb ..